# Parsing expressions from a file and stock keywords in a dictionary

Tags: python

0

I'm trying to parse a file and get from it the variables and the intervals in which they live. For example, an input file might contain something like this:

```
Constants

 x1 = 1;   

Variables

x45 in [-45,5844];

x63 in [0,456];

x41 in [45, 1.e8]; #Where 1.e8 stands for 10^8
```

All I want to do is to stock every couple (variable, interval) in a dictionary. If it's a constant, the interval would be [constant, constant]. I first imagined I had to use the built-in function findall to search through the whole file all the lines of the type "x"random_number" in "random_interval" or "x"random_number = random_number" but I don't know how to get and stock the "x" and the intervals after I find all the lines I wanted.

Also, whenever there is a "1.e8" in an interval, I want to replace it by a "10**8" before stocking it in the dictionary.
If the file above is passed as an argument, the code would return this :

```
{"x1" : [1,1], "x45" : [-45,5844], "x63" : [0,456], "x41" : [45,10**8]}
```

Honestly I don't exactly know how to begin. All I did is this :

```
from sys import argv
import re

script, filename = argv
#The file which contains the variables is filename, so that I can use as a command 
#in a terminal : "python myscript.py filename.txt"

file_data = open(filename, 'r')
Dict = {} #The dictionnary in which I want to store the variables and the intervals
txt = file_data.read()  

#Here I thought I might use this : re.findall(.*"in".*, txt) or something like that 
#but It will get me all the lines of the type "blabla in bloblo".
#I want also blabla and bloblo so that I can put them into my dictionnary like this : 
#Dict[blabla] = bloblo
#In the dictionnary it will be for example Dict = {x45 : [-10, 456]}

file_data.close()
```

Any clue ?

Thanks for helping me to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like this:

```
from sys import argv
import re

script, filename = argv
#The file which contains the variables is filename, so that I can use as a command 
#in a terminal : "python myscript.py filename.txt"
# A pattern I've whipped up which will hopefully match your case although I don't know what possible variations you may have
variable_pattern = re.compile("(x\d+) in \[(.*), *(.*)\];")
constant_pattern = re.compile("(x\d+) = (.*);")
variable_dict = {}
with open(filename) as file_data:
    for line in file_data:
        match = variable_pattern.search(line)
        if match is not None:
            groups = match.groups()
            # We'll assume that the values found can be converted to a float
            variable_dict[groups[0]] = [float(val) for val in groups[1:]]
            continue
        match = constant_pattern.search(line)
        if match is not None:
            groups = match.groups()
            # Not sure if this is what you want, I didn't really understand why you repeated the value 1 in your example
            variable_dict[groups[0]] = [float(groups[1]), float(groups[1])]
    
print(variable_dict)
```

If you need to alter your regular expression, then https://regexr.com/ can be a neat tool to help those unfamiliar with them.

Comment: Thank you for your rapid answer sir. I think I've understood the main elements of your code but what is filepath from ? Is it related to the file "filename" which is passed as an argument ? Also, what if there are other lines in the file after the typical "blabla in bloblo" which could errorly match with the pattern you have used and that I don't want to be parsed for this ?

Comment: Yeah, edited, just a typo on my part. I've also made a correct to the constant_pattern

Comment: You can make the pattern more or less restrictive as you desire, you can add "$" to the end of the match pattern to ensure that no other characters follow the pattern and you can add "^" at the start to ensure nothing comes before the pattern.

Comment: for example "^(x\d+) in \[(.*), *(.*)\];$" will match "x63 in [0,456];" but it will not match "x63 in [0,456]; abc". In the case of a failed match the variable "match" will be "None" and so the line will be ignored.

Comment: I repeat when there is a constant because I have to make this parsing in order to use these variables and the intervals they are in for a solver which will treat them in a standard form. So I have to have all these intervals in the same form. In any case, I thank you well for your rapid and precise answers, I'll test it

Comment: @BJBChessEmperor Did this end up answering your question?